# How to detect JPA mapped fields with Java Reflection

Tags: java, jpa, reflection

I need to iterate over my class and figure out what are the fields that are JPA mapped and are not transient. I don't want to check for every annotation over the fields, is any shortcut to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Annotation annotation = field.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);

Comment: I dont wanna check if the field have my annotation, I want to check if it is JPA persistent, which are two completely different things. Anyway thanks for trying help me out :)

Comment: tried the JPA metamodel?

Comment: What you mean? @NeilStockton

Comment: EntityManagerFactory.getMetaModel. Tells you plenty of things about the different entities. Present in all basic JPA javadocs

Comment: Interesting, I will give it a try, thanks :)